# Java: DateTimeFormatter and parsing sub-seconds

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

Why is DateTimeFormatter able to format a fraction of a second but not able to parse it?

The code below fails at the parse if I do not replace the fmt to "yyyyMMddHHmmss" (remove the SS at the end);

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{    
  String fmt = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSS";
  ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ();
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern (fmt).withZone (ZoneOffset.UTC);
  String s = dtf.format (now);
  ZonedDateTime x = ZonedDateTime.parse (s, dtf);
}
```

Exception is

```
Text '2018071819500784' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @JacobG. https://ideone.com/e5qR7C

Comment: @YCF_L That's running JDK 8; I'm running 10 and can't reproduce it.

Comment: It is not working with 3 S too.

Comment: Yes @JacobG. I think it is a bug in Java 8 I use both Java 8 and Java 10 in Java 10 it work fine

Comment: Reproducible on Java 8.

Comment: TL;DR for the linked duplicate question: it's a bug in JDK8 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085). Workaround is to create the formatter via `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").appendValue(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3).toFormatter()` - but only groups of 3, 6, and 9 digits are supported for milliseconds.